# My SPARQL query doesn't work at all

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am currently trying to run my query but I keep getting the error that in line 0 the parentheses are not balanced at '}'

I have checked my whole code multiple times, but I don't seem to get it fixed. I am currently using the dbpedia endpoint.

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX  dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?government  ?population
WHERE{ ?country  dct:subject  <http://dbpedia.org/resource>/Category:Countries_in_Europe> ;
 rdfs:label ?country;         
dbo:government  ?government.
?government rdfs:label ?government.
?population rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:PopulatedPlace
rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Country;
rdfs:label ?country ; 
prop:populationEstimate ?population . 
FILTER (?population < 3000000) . 
FILTER ( lang(?country) AND (lang(?(government = 'en')
}
```

Three rows in the graph should be shown, First with the country as a title, second with the governmenttypes of the countries as a title and the 3rd should be a row with the population descending from the total of 3000000.

Thanks alot in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Your whole query is broken. Using the same variable as subject and then as placeholder for the label will never work. E.g. the `?country` variable. And then, what is the goal of the population triple pattern (population is a literal value)? And why do you assume to get three rows back then? That's not how SPARQL works. The set of triple patterns is used as intersection, technically this are joins on common variables. You can get one row for each country and then the values, but not threee rows per country

Comment: And your FILTER is broken

Comment: And the URI of Countries_in_Europe. Come on, this are really odd mistakes that you should see by yourself

Comment: And... I think the wish is not three *rows* but three *columns*.

Comment: And the property is called governmentType ...

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple errors in this query.

Several things that pop out at me.

Thing 1 --

```
?government rdfs:label ?government.
```

You've got several similar `?subject ?predicate ?subject` constructions.

Thing 2 --

```
?population rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:PopulatedPlace
rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Country;
```

I think you need a semicolon after `dbo:PopulatedPlace`

Thing 3 --

```
FILTER ( lang(?country) AND (lang(?(government = 'en')
```

That `FILTER` breaks syntax several ways.  I think this will do what you intend --

```
FILTER ( lang(?country)    = 'en') .
FILTER ( lang(?government) = 'en') .
```

Thing 4 --

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource>/Category:Countries_in_Europe>
```

You've got an extra `>` in mid-string.

Thing 5 --

```
dbpedia-owl:Country
```

I think that should be `dbo:Country`

Thing 6 --

```
prop:populationEstimate
```

I think that should be `dbp:populationEstimate`

There are MANY more issues...  I am not sure you're really trying.

Comment: government -> governmentType

Comment: population -> populationTotal